# How to configure Login auth in GoLang with Go-Fiber & MongoDb Database

Tags: mongodb, go, go-fiber

In the below code my **Register** function is working well but the **login** function is showing an error with goroutines.

*panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x2f0 pc=0x920427]*

Please update me with a solution for this login, you can make a whole new login function just clear my concepts here.

```
var client *mongo.Client


func Register(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    var data map[string]string

    if err := c.BodyParser(&data); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    passwd, _ := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(data["password"]), 10)

    user := models.User{
        Name:     data["name"],
        Email:    data["email"],
        Password: passwd,
    }

    _, err := dao.UserData(&user)
    if err != nil {
        return c.JSON(err)
    } else {
        response := models.Response{
            Message: "User Registered",
            Success: true,
        }
        return c.JSON(response)

    }
}


func Login(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    var data map[string]string

    if err := c.BodyParser(&data); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var user models.User
    var dbUser models.User

    collection := client.Database("Shashank").Collection("User")
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    err := collection.FindOne(ctx, bson.M{"email": user.Email}).Decode(&dbUser)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fiber.StatusBadRequest)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(fiber.StatusOK)
    }

    if err := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword(user.Password, []byte(data["passwd"])); err != nil {
        c.Status(fiber.StatusBadRequest)
        return c.JSON(fiber.Map{
            "message": "incorrect password",
        })
    }
    return c.JSON(user)
}
```

Comment: found a similar implementation on github, check this link https://github.com/EricLau1/go-fiber-auth-api/blob/master/controllers/auth.go

Comment: Not working code 



Showing Error - no reachable servers
panic: no reachable servers

exit status 2

Answer (score 0):

the first line in `Login` func is `var data map[string]string`

that does not assign any memory - merely initializes variable `data` to be of type `map[string]string`. [The zero value of map type is nil](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/19).

so in the next line when you do `c.BodyParser(&data)` - `&data` is trying to dereference a nil pointer - and hence your error.

change the first line to `data := map[string]string{}`. Now there is a memory allocation and hence a valid memory that `&data` can dereference.

Comment: That didn't work.

Comment: Now showing 153 + goroutine error plus the same error above

Comment: what is the structure of `dbUser` of type `mongo.Database`- you're decoding to it - it seems fishy to me.

Comment: type User struct {
 Name     string `bson:"name"`;
 Email    string `bson:"email"`;
 Password []byte;
}





type Response struct {
 Message string `json: "message"`;
 Success bool   `json: "success"`
}


I've used semicolumn ; in the above code here just for better understanding

Comment: I think you've initialized `dbUser` wrongly to type `mongo.Database`. initialize it to the type `User` your comment mentions and try again.

Comment: No, the db user is just a reference of the User struct as I have created another package for models where I have created User struct & Response struct

Comment: dude read your code - `var dbUser mongo.Database` thats what you've written - change it to `var dbUser models.User`.

Comment: Not working still the error is the same. I think that error is caused by somewhere else.

I am too new to Golang so I am getting stuck with that.

Comment: I want to create a Signup & login program with the use of Go-fibre & MongoDB.

Is there any other way I can try

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK maps usually have to be properly initialised with `make()`. Try swapping

```golang
var data map[string]string
```

with

```golang
data := make(map[string]string)
```